# c++ observer pattern: adding another dimension

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement this pattern on a "smart building" system design (using STL library). Various "sensors" placed in rooms, floors etc, dispatch signals that are handled by "controllers" (also placed in different rooms, floors etc.). The problem I'm facing is that the controller's subscription to an event isn't just event based, it is also location based.

For example, controller A can subscribe to a fire signal from room #1 in floor #4 and to a motion signal in floor #5. A floor-based subscription means that controller A will get an motion event about every room in the floor he's subscribed to (assuming the appropriate sensor is placed there). There's also a building-wide subscription for that matter.

The topology of the system is read from a configuration file at start up, so I don't want to map the whole building, just the relevant places that contain sensors and controllers.

What I've managed to think of :

**Option 1:** MonitoredArea class that contains the name of the area (Building1, Floor 2, Room 3) and a vector where the vector's index is an enumerated event type each member of the vector contains a list of controllers that are subscribed to this event. The class will also contain a pointer to a parent MonitoredArea, in the case it is a room in a floor, or a floor in a building.

A Sensor class will dispatch an Event to a center hub along with the sensor's name. The hub will run it through his sensor-name-to-location map, acquire the matching MonitoredArea and will alert all the controllers in the vector.

**Cons**:

- Coupling of the location to the controller
- Events are enumerated and are hard coded in the MonitoredArea class, adding future events is difficult.
  [image]

**Option 2**:
Keeping all the subscriptions in the Controller class.

**Cons**:

- Very inefficient. Every event will make the control center to iterate through all the controller and find out which are subscribed to this particular event.

**Option 3:**
Event based functionality. Event class (ie. FireEvent) will contain all the locations it can happen in (according to the sensor's setup) and for every location, a list of the controllers that are subscribed to it.

[image]

**Cons**:

- A map of maps
- Strong data duplication
- No way to alert floor-based subscriptions about events in the various rooms.

As you can see, I'm not happy with any of the mentioned solutions. I'm sure I've reached the over-thinking stage and would be happy for a feedback or alternative suggestions as to how I approach this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is design pattern (sort of speak) used a lot in game development called "Message Bus". And it is sometimes used to replace event based operations.

"A message bus is a connection between one or more senders and/or receivers. Think of it like a connection between computers in a bus topology: Every node can send a message by passing it to the bus, and all connected nodes will receive that message. If the node is processed and if a reply is sent is completely up to each receiver itself.

Having modules connected to a message bus gives us some advantages:

Every module is isolated, it does not need to know of any others.
Every module can react to any message that’s being sent to the bus; that means you get extra flexibility for free, without increasing dependencies at all.
It’s much easier to follow the YAGNI workflow: For example you’re going to add weapons. At first you implement the physics, then you add visuals in the renderer, and then playing sounds. All of those features can be implemented independently at any time, without interrupting each other.
You save yourself from thinking a lot about how to connect certain modules to each other. Sometimes it takes a huge amount of time, including drawing diagrams/dependency graphs."

Sources:
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/event-queue.html

http://www.optank.org/2013/04/02/game-development-design-3-message-bus/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Question: how is the message bus different from a simple event loop?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but this is a different way of implementing method dispatching on typed languages. For instance you could send messages on the the bus and using some struct with an ID and some data and if another class is interested on that particular id (There are a number of implementations of this) can handle it. There is no direct function call between objects directly as it is in regular method  call message dispatching.